# How to use Angular2 Directives to add material icon

Tags: typescript, angular-material, angular2-directives

I have this code to add a search icon to an input, and it works fine

`<md-form-field>
    <span mdPrefix><md-icon>search</md-icon></span>
    <input type="text" mdInput>
</md-form-field>`

Because the actual code is more complex than above and very repetitive I would like to encapsulate this in a @Directive that looks like this.

`<md-form-field>
    <input type="text" mdInput addSearchMatIcon>
</md-form-field>`

Of course an option is to encapsule all of this inside a @Component, that is easy, but I will lose access to edit input attributes that I need to customize depending on the where I need to use. And I don't want to write a property to all the potencial input customization options

Comment: What have you done so far to implement this?

Comment: Why not `<md-icon mdPrefix>search</md-icon>` that's a little simple.

Comment: William the code is more complex I tried to made a simple question simplifying the code

Comment: Edric I'm using a @Component to encapsulate the code with the mentioned problems